# ¿Por qué una adaptación de la función get_result llena los array pero no muestra dato en PHP 5.3?

Tags: php

Conseguí una función adaptada del comando `get_result` para PHP 5.3:

```
function get_result($Statement) {
    $RESULT = array();
    $Statement->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
        $PARAMS = array();
        while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
        $Statement->fetch();
    }
    return $RESULT;
}

/*$resultados = $stmtx->get_result();*/
$RESULT = get_result($stmtx);
while ( $datos = array_shift($RESULT) ) {
}
```

Hice un `var_dump` de resultados y me regresa todos los arrays perfectamente. Resultados de la consulta:

```
array(38) { 
    [0]=> array(21) {
        ["id_omd"]=> int(20) 
        ["unidad"]=> string(12) "033100000000" 
        ["cedula_sancionado"]=> int(17739707) 
        ["cedula_sancionador"]=> int(8644097) 
        ["cedula_superior"]=> int(8644097) 
        ["articulo_falta"]=> int(35) 
        ["aparte_falta"]=> int(1) 
        ["documento_seleccion"]=> string(3) "2-1" 
        ["fecha_inicio"]=> string(10) "2017-03-23" 
        ["fecha_termino"]=> string(10) "2017-03-24" 
        ["dias_sancion"]=> int(1) 
        ["aclaratoria_sancion"]=> string(17) " qwrqwrwqrq wr wq" 
        ["estado_lugar_id"]=> int(2) 
        ["estado_sancion_id"]=> int(1) 
        ["fecha_proceso"]=> NULL 
        ["medida_id"]=> int(2) 
        ["articulo_circunstancias"]=> int(40) 
        ["agravante_seleccion"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["atenuante_seleccion"]=> string(3) "1-6" 
        ["total_medida"]=> float(0) 
        ["total_demerito_final"]=> float(6.25) 
    } 
    [1]=> ....
```

Pero no crea los registros en la tabla.

Asi hago el llamado de los datos:

```
$cedula = $datos["cedula_sancionado"];
```

¿Qué error puede ocurrir?

Hice un `var_dump` de `$datos` dentro del `while` y solo muestra esto una sola vez (parece que el ciclo no se repite y sólo hace un elemento):

```
{
    ["id_omd"]=> int(20) 
    ["unidad"]=> string(12) "033100000000" 
    ["cedula_sancionado"]=> int(17739707) 
    ["cedula_sancionador"]=> int(8644097) 
    ["cedula_superior"]=> int(8644097) 
    ["articulo_falta"]=> int(35) 
    ["aparte_falta"]=> int(1) 
    ["documento_seleccion"]=> string(3) "2-1" 
    ["fecha_inicio"]=> string(10) "2017-03-23" 
    ["fecha_termino"]=> string(10) "2017-03-24" 
    ["dias_sancion"]=> int(1) 
    ["aclaratoria_sancion"]=> string(17) " qwrqwrwqrq wr wq" 
    ["estado_lugar_id"]=> int(2) 
    ["estado_sancion_id"]=> int(1) 
    ["fecha_proceso"]=> NULL 
    ["medida_id"]=> int(2) 
    ["articulo_circunstancias"]=> int(40) 
    ["agravante_seleccion"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["atenuante_seleccion"]=> string(3) "1-6" 
    ["total_medida"]=> float(0) 
    ["total_demerito_final"]=> float(6.25) 
}
```

Comment: `$RESULT = get_result($stmtx);
while ( $datos = array_shift($RESULT) ) {
}` para que es eso? hay donde muestras tu resultado ????, ps puede ser que te falte algun alert para indicar que se cumplio la funcion o simplemente para mostrar el resultado de lo que contiene no ?

Comment: @CriticalGhost es una funcion de adaptacion de get_result para PHP 5.3

Comment: ¿La variable `$datos` contiene lo que pones como resultado de la consulta? ¿Qué mensaje de error recibes cuando haces `$cedula = $datos["cedula_sancionado"];`?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hice un var_dump de $RESULT y me muestra como 40 lineas llenas de los arrays que jala, e hice un echo $resultados y muestra 46 registros que son los existentes.

Si hago el var_dump dentro del while solo jala un registro, es decir, una linea de registro. $cedula no se muestra, ni siquiera muestrta las columnas en HTML. probare hacer var_dump de datos

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya hice el var_dump. parece que el ciclo no se repite, porque solo ejecutp un solo var_dump y mas nada

Comment: porque mejor no haces un for?

Comment: un while no te funcionara de mucho EJ supongamos que tenemos una variable _A_ que tiene el valor _1_ si hago un `while(A=1){}` esa funcion siempre se cumplira ya que solo tiene 1 valor, pero cuando tienes varios valores siempre cogera el primero que vea, pero no los demas, yo te recomiendo que hagas un for :3

Comment: @CriticalGhost y como seria el for con esos datos?

Comment: mmmmm, bueno dejame pensar un poco, tendria que modificar un poquito el codigo del while

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol porque mejor no entras al chat :)

Comment: El bucle `for` o `while` no debería importar (siempre que se haga bien). No termino de comprender por qué quieres hacer la función `get_result` en PHP 5.3 cuando precisamente está disponible a partir de PHP 5.3 (aunque eso no afecta a la pregunta, es sólo curiosidad)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si esta disponible, porque no me funciona? que ocurre entonces alvaro? tengo PHP 5.3.3 squeezy pero no tengo MYSQLND instalado y no puedo instalarlo

Comment: no creen que seria mejor ir al chat?, ya veo muchos comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenia tres problemas:

1) Tenia el codigo de esta forma:

```
while ( $datos = array_shift($RESULT) ) {
}

<tr><th></tr> // Encabezado de la tabla


$cedula=$datos["cedula_sancionado"];

<tr> // Tabla
<input type="text" value="<?=$cedula=?>
```

Por lo tanto se estaban generando los registros donde estaba el encabezado de la tabla:

Solucion:

```
<tr><th></tr> // Encabezado de la tabla

while ( $datos = array_shift($RESULT) ) {
}
$cedula=$datos["cedula_sancionado"];

<tr> // Tabla
<input type="text" value="<?=$cedula=?>
```

2) Luego de este cambio solo generaba los datos obtenidos de la tabla *sanciones*, luego hacia una consulta para obtener descripciones de algunos ID que tenia la tabla para eso tenia algo asi:

```
$stmt=$conexion2->prepare(...)

En realidad era $conexion3.
```

3) Luego funciono perfectamente